# Transactional verb in URL: do or don't?

Tags: ecommerce, site-structure, url-slug

Imagine, you have around 10 years old online print shop and you make it ready for relaunch. Its URL conception is logical, like:

- Category: /shop/category.html
- Product: /shop/category/product.html

But multiple categories have not unified slugs, like:

- books.html
- print-banners.html
- print-personalized-gifts.html
- imprint-caps-and-hats.html

The question: would you unify category slugs before/while relaunch?
Like

- books.html
- banners.html
- gifts.html
- caps.html

I must add: there are no violations of URL conception, it isn't like: some categories are /category.html, and some other are /category/. Or some products are placed on the category level. No, there are no such errors. It goes only about slug namings, which aren't unified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a descriptive url enhances your SEO ranking a tad, Google does not care about how you have organised your website internally.

It is entirely up to you and it can be a matter of opinion or taste, or simply to organise your code. A good reason to have descriptive urls is to help the user.

If you are going to reorganise it later, then it is better to do it now so as to not disrupt your SEO ranking